# Image is transparent all the way to the background but not header color

Tags: html, css

I have header line in blue, content box in white and background in light blue.
And when I try to add my .png logo without background into header its background inherts my pages background and not header line color.
It shows like this:
index:

```
<body>
      <div id="header_tip"></div>
      <header>
          <h1 id="logo">
              <img src="logo.png"/>
          </h1>
      </header>
      <div id="content">


      </div>

</body>
```

css:

```
* {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  font-family:"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Sans-serif;
  word-spacing:-2px;
  background-color: #e8fdff;
}

#header_tip {
    height: 15px;
    margin: 10px 5% 0% 5%;
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: 1px 0px 5px #2c868e;
}
header {
    height: 90px;
    background-color: rgb(44, 134, 142);
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;

    left: 0;
    z-index: 999;

    -webkit-transition: height 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: height 0.3s;
    -ms-transition: height 0.3s;
    -o-transition: height 0.3s;
    transition: height 0.3s;
}

header.smaller {
    height: 40px;
}

#content {
    height: 1500px;
    float: center;
    margin: 0px 5% 15px 5%;
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #2c868e;
}
#header_tip.smaller {
    background-color: black;
    margin: 0px;
    height: 0px;
}
```

I'm using this script which makes header resize and follow while scrolling

Comment: got a link to the site?

Comment: Where are the styles for `#logo` and what are the dimensions of the logo image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you are applying a light blue background to every element, in this rule:

```
* {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  font-family:"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Sans-serif;
  word-spacing:-2px;
  background-color: #e8fdff;
}
```

The `*` selector means *any element*, so this is being applied to your PNG image, and the background colour is showing through due to the alpha transparency.

Separate the rule into two more appropriate rules, like this:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: #e8fdff;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  word-spacing: -2px;
}
```

Voila. [Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/on5kdtun/.)

Comment: Yes, that was the case. Thanks a lot now everything works great! :)